# .htaccess, X-frame-options not overriding value instead duplicate show in network tab

Tags: iframe, same-origin-policy, x-frame-options, .htaccess

Duplicate values are shown of X-frame-options in network tab.

I'm trying to override the header value through,.htaccess file. Instead of overriding the value its shown duplicated.

Header always set X-Frame-Options "*"

[View coming result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hraoA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This was the server side issue my cloud hosting provider resolved this.